How check is form has been updated (dirty) from a header?
My application is roughly structured as such:
<app-header></app-header> <app-main></app-main> <app-footer></app-footer>
The header contains a link to this command:
this.keycloakService.logout();
It bypasses the "if (component.form.dirty)" in the main part. I would like to ask the users if they want to save when it happens.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please clarify your quesion and add more details.

You can use a canDeactivate guard on your form route definition for this. A simple example is given below:
// route

{
  path: APP_PATHS.SECTION.ASSIGN + '/:personId',
  loadComponent: () =>
    import(
      '../person/person-assign/person-assign.component'
    ).then((m) => m.PersonAssignComponent),
  canDeactivate: [formDeactivateGuard]
}

// guard

import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivateFn } from '@angular/router';
import { DialogService } from '@shared/services/dialog.service';
import { FormService } from '@shared/services/form.service';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export const formDeactivateGuard: CanDeactivateFn<any> = async () => {
    const formService = inject(FormService);
    const dialogService = inject(DialogService);

    if (formService._isDirty.getValue()) {
        return await dialogService
            .openConfirmDialog({
                title: 'form.unsaved-changes.title',
                message: 'form.unsaved-changes.message',
                confirmKey: 'common.leave',
                cancelKey: 'common.cancel',
            })
            .then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    formService.setDirty(false);
                    return Promise.resolve(true);
                } else {
                    return Promise.resolve(false);
                }
            });
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
};


// service 

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FormService {
    public _isDirty = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    public setDirty(isDirty: boolean) {
        this._isDirty.next(isDirty);
    }
}

Use the service in your form component to set the dirty state on valueChanges.
There are many ways to achieve this, and your use case will determine which one is right for you. Here we are using a service that allows us to have full control over the form dirty state (I use this in case the user has made changes but then those changes are the same as the original values which in effect equals no change), you could alternatively use an abstract component that monitors the forms state and provides it to the guard, reducing repetition.

Thanks for your detailed answer. Unfortunatly, I already uses canDeactivate on my routes to test my forms but the logout command do not trigger it.

I guess your logout command does not trigger a route change until after logged out. You can still use the service solution provided above and query the form state from your logout component (in the same way the deactivate guard does if (formService._isDirty.getValue()) { // throw dialog } else { logout() }}
